# How to show multiple records in just 1 detail band or group header

Tags: jasper-reports

i am new to iReport/jasper. I have this simple scenario: 
I have two fields: recordno & name. Now, I have 3 names in my db with the same recordno: name: John, Mark and Steve. Now, I want to show the 3 names (*with parameter of the same recordno value*) in just one detail or a group header, however, my output shows the 3 names **but in 3 details/group as well**. How to prevent this? Or how to group or combine them as one?

**Expected Result:**

```
-------DETAIL/GROUP BAND-------
John
Mark
Steve
-----------end----------------
```

**Unexpected Result:**

```
-------DETAIL/GROUP BAND-------
John
-----------end----------------
-------DETAIL/GROUP BAND-------
Mark<br>
-----------end-----------------
-------DETAIL/GROUP BAND-------
Steve<br>
-----------end-----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in two ways:

The first:

- Create a Group band based on recordNo.
- Create a Detail band and put your name field.

The second:

- Create a Group band based on recordNo.
- Create a sub report with input parameter your collection and in the sub report put your name field.

Tell me, if it's OK